# Formula return cell defined name

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to use cell address and return the cell defined name, i.e.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,,"SHEET 001"))
```

I need this `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()` to refer to the current cell defined name
i.e. "sales" and not `$A$1`

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a quick workaround, though admittedly, a little limited.

1. do a Paste List of all defined names in a clear area of a sheet.
2. The following formula will create a string resembling the fully qualified cell address you're looking for, matching it in the list, and returning the cell name from the adjacent column
   =INDEX(NameList,MATCH("='"&SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"fully_qualified_filename","")&"'!"&CELL("address"),NameReferences,0))

It's obviously limited to names pointing to a single cell, but it could be extended to search cell ranges.

It works for me because the name of the cell displaying the data is the name of the data field, so no matter where I put it, the reference will always be correct.

While I'm working on the project I included a statement in an often-run macro that refreshes the Names list to keep it current.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot take credit for writing this code, but it does precisely what you need. I needed the same feature some years ago, and stumbled upon this code somewhere in cyberspace, perhaps modified it a bit, but I can't remember either way. It's worked great for me.

It works like this:

1. Paste the code below into a VBA module of an Excel macro-enabled workbook (*.xlsm).
2. Then, type into an Excel worksheet cell something like  "=CellName(F19)" and it will return something like "rngSomeNamedCell".

Here is the code:

```
Public Function CellName(cel As Range) As Variant
Dim nm As Name
    For Each nm In Names
        If nm.RefersTo = "=" & cel.Parent.Name & "!" & cel.Address Then
            CellName = nm.Name
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
CellName = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built in excel function that will do this.  You could use a user defined function to return the cell name.

The two functions below will return the name of the cell.  One takes a cell refernce, the other takes a row and column.  Both are only set up to work on the local sheet right now but you could add an optional variable to take a worksheet name if required.

First function would be called with `=cell_name()`

Gordon

```
Function cell_name() As String
dim rng as Range
On Error Resume Next

set rng = activeCell

If Len(rng.Name.Name) < 0 Then
    cell_name = "No named Range"
    Exit Function
End If

cell_name = rng.Name.Name

if instr("cell_name","!")>0 then
    cell_name = Right(cell_name, Len(cell_name) - InStr(cell_name, "!"))
end if

End Function
```

second function returns cell name from a given row and column

```
Function cell_name2(r As Long, c As Long) As String
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Cells(r, c)
On Error Resume Next

If Len(rng.Name.Name) < 0 Then
    cell_name = "No named Range"
    Exit Function
End If

cell_name2 = rng.Name.Name

End Function
```

Edited first function to work on the activecell.

Comment: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,,"SHEET 001"))`
This formula works as special cell reference. it will refer to it own cell address name but in sheet 001.
while i have different cell locations i.e. `A1` is `A2` in other sheet.
I define cells with names, so that `sales` will have same value all over the workbook.

Comment: I've changed the first formula to work on the cell with the formula in it.  You should be able to use the funtion `=INDIRECT("'SHEET 001'!" &cell_name())` to make this work for you.